# Code reduction possible with modulo operator?

Tags: java, optimization, mathematics

I'm trying to model a puzzle in order to resolve it with the Choco solver.

One of the constraint I'm coding is cyclical (it's triplet which follow themselves) like the following example:

```
s.post(LogicalConstraintFactory.ifThen(
    IntConstraintFactory.member(mvt[i], new int[]{1, 2, 3}),
    IntConstraintFactory.not_member(mvt[i + 1], new int[]{1, 2, 3})
));
s.post(LogicalConstraintFactory.ifThen(
    IntConstraintFactory.member(mvt[i], new int[]{4, 5, 6}),
    IntConstraintFactory.not_member(mvt[i + 1], new int[]{4, 5, 6})
));
s.post(LogicalConstraintFactory.ifThen(
    IntConstraintFactory.member(mvt[i], new int[]{7, 8, 9}),
    IntConstraintFactory.not_member(mvt[i + 1], new int[]{7, 8, 9})
));
// and so one...
```

I think that my library isn't very known so the mathematics equivalent is :

```
if(foo[i] is in {1, 2, 3}) then
    foo[i+1] shouldn't be in {1, 2, 3}
if(foo[i] is in {4, 5, 6}) then
    foo[i+1] shouldn't be in {4, 5, 6}
...
```

Any idea of how I can model this problem with modulo (to avoid writing each triplet)?

Comment: How consistent are your int values... is it always triples, and always starting from 1 (i.e. always `[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[....],...` )

Comment: @rolfl Yes, it's always triplet and starting from 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the choco solver, but would this solve your problem?

```
s.post(IntConstraintFactory.not_member(mvt[i+1], 
   new int[] { (mvt[i]/3)*3 + 1, (mvt[i]/3)*3 + 2, (mvt[i]/3)*3 + 3}));
```

Another option might be:

```
s.post(LogicalConstraintFactory.not(
  IntConstraintFactory.eucl_div(mvt[i+1]-1, 3, (int)(mvt[i]-1)/3)));
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/chocoteam/choco3/blob/develop/choco-solver/src/main/java/solver/constraints/IntConstraintFactory.java):

```
/**
 * Ensures DIVIDEND / DIVISOR = RESULT, rounding towards 0 -- Euclidean division
 *
 * @param DIVIDEND dividend
 * @param DIVISOR  divisor
 * @param RESULT   result
 */
```

Answer (score 6):

If your triplets were zero-based (i.e., {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, …) then the answer might have been more obvious.  As it is, you have to apply an offset of -1, then divide by three to figure out which triplet an element belongs to.

```
if ((mvt[i] - 1) / 3 == (mvt[i + 1] - 1) / 3) {
    // This shouldn't happen: mvt[i] and mvt[i + 1] are in the same triplet
}
```

Comment: That's the sentiment that I want to express, but I see that `mvt` consists of `IntVar`s, not `int`s, so you can't just perform ordinary arithmetic on them. However, I can't figure out how to express that using Choco solver constraints — and neither has anyone else so far.

Comment: You can consider `IntVar` as `int`, I'll perform by myself the arithmetic to choco library translation. Don't care about it.

Answer (score 4):

If the process is consistently 123, then 456, etc. and the check is always 'if a value is in one triplet, then the next value is not allowed in the same triplet, then you can have the following simple function:

```
int thisval = mvt[i];
// because thisval triplets are 1-based, you need to offset by -1 on the modulo
int excludemin = (thisval - ((thisval - 1) % 3));
int excludemax = excludemin + 3;
if (mvt[i+1] >= excludemin && mvt[i+1] < excludemax) {
    // this is not supposed to happen....
    // the i+1 element is inside the same triplet.
}
```

I am not sure how this would fit in your paradigm.... but, it is just one test for your whole system